# Neatest way to 'reset' all static variables in a .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-members

Horribleness aside, if I have a .NET webapp which has static variables scattered across multiple classes, what is neatest way to 'clear' them all back to null.

Off the top of my head, it would be to restart the application using

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()
```

Reasons behind the question - 
We are caching a few very large Dictionary collections which are expensive to create, and on the odd occasion need to be reset.

Comment: Could you give more reasons behind wanting to do so, and whether it would be feasible *not* to use static variables to start with?

Comment: a web app with static variables?? sounds very adventurous and not really suitable for load balancing.

Comment: Recursive reflection of the entire assembly, perchance? Can't go wrong with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unloading sounds the simplest way, but you wouldn't want to do that very frequently; frankly I would be very dubious of any routine requirement to do this.

If you wanted to do it *without* unloading, you'd have to look on a case-by-case basis to understand the implications. In particular, forcibly setting something to null that was set to a value by the static constructor / type initializer / static field initializer could thoroughly break your application.

Note that static variables are rarely suitable for web apps, except perhaps for caches (and then must be carefully managed).

If you genuinely do have data like this, rather than multiple static variables you might look at *instance* variables on a state class that is help as a pseudo-singleton - then you only have one reference to swap per cluster of data.

Something that *might* be worth considering is having an event somewhere that the static code can subscribe to **once only** when initializing themselves, then trigger the event when needed, i.e.

```
myStaticData = new SomeExpensiveThreadSafeCacheDictionary();
GlobalKillSwitch.ResetCache += delegate { myStaticData.Clear(); };
```

Comment: "static variables are rarely suitable for web apps" - why? I'm not questioning whether you're right or not, genuinely interested as to why - can't seem to find any further info on google.

Comment: @SkonJeet because web applications are dealing with many many requests; most of the data used in a request is specific to that request, and you wouldn't want it anywhere near a static field that could impact other requests. When you **do** use a static field, you need to consider thread-safety (both of multiple competing unrelated requests, and of a single request jumping between different threads during the pipeline). Don't get me wrong: they have a use... but: with lots of caveats

Comment: @SkonJeet Also, ASP.NET usually means IIS. IIS recycles worker process at will, on recycle the static variable is binned. Constantly having to re-initialise it might be a problem depending on what it is used for.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth It would only be re-initialised on demand, and therefore no more often than if it was on a per-context basis.

Comment: @maxp This is why I said depending on what it is used for. If you mistakenly use it to cache something then this will mean your cache is doing more fetches than it needs to.

Answer (score 3):

I use this

```
    public static void ResetAllStaticsVariables(Type type)
    {
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
        {
            fieldInfo.SetValue(null, GetDefault(type));
        }
    }

    public static object GetDefault(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType)
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I found this answer trying to reset the desktop app's state between integration tests' runs, it's really good for it.